# A "Crookedness criterion" for a pair of orthogonal projectors?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, projection

If $P$ is an orthogonal projector on a Hilbert space $H$, then
$\,\operatorname{im}P=(\ker P)^\perp\subset H\,$ is a closed subspace, also called the support of $P$. And vice versa: Every closed subspace determines a  unique orthogonal projector, having the given subspace as support.

Let $Q$ be another orthogonal projector. Then we have

- $\operatorname{im}P\perp\operatorname{im}Q\iff PQ=0\,,$
- $\operatorname{im}P\subset\operatorname{im}Q\iff PQ=P\,.$

Both points are not hard to prove and are found in many textbooks.
My question is, if these can be condensed into one criterion as follows:

> Does the equivalence
>   $$\operatorname{Im}P\cap\operatorname{Im}Q=\{0\}\iff\|PQ\|<1\tag{1}$$
>   hold?
>   How can it be proved/disproved?

Note that the RHS condition of $(1)$ is also symmetric since 
$\|PQ\|=\|(QP)^*\|=\|QP\|$
by the orthogonality of the projectors and the isometry of the involution.

I did some textbook and online search but only came up with the "extreme" cases $\|\cdot\|\in\{0,1\}$ corresponding to the explicit points as of above.
Starting from the RHS and using as ansatz the definition of the operator norm was tried, but I couldn't see how to get through ...

---

The validity of $(1)$ would permit to define an angle between the subspaces  by $\,\cos\gamma= \|PQ\|\,$, thus measuring the "crookedness" between the projectors or their associated subspaces, respectively.

If $\,P=(\,\cdot\,| u_P)\,u_P\,$ and $\,Q=(\,\cdot\,|u_Q)\,u_Q\,$ are $1$-dimensional orthogonal projectors onto $\operatorname{span}\{u_P\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{u_Q\}$, respectively, then
$$\|QP\| = \|PQ\| = |(u_P|u_Q)|$$
which fits well with a possible interpretation of $\|PQ\|$ as $\,\cos\gamma$.

Comment: I believe example 4.6(ii) on page 15 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.1004.pdf has a counterexample.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this lovely paper by Halmos:
https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-144-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251519-5/S0002-9947-1969-0251519-5.pdf

Comment: @Peter , thank you for both ref's: A few days before I found Halmos' article, now after your pointer I looked more carefully through it. The arxiv paper on Modular theory is also worthwhile, including the counterexample. However, supinf's answer is more accessible and more tailored to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a counterexample in $\ell^2$.

Let $A:=\{x\in\ell^2 : x_{2n} = n x_{2n+1}\;\forall n\in\mathbb N\}$
and let $B:=\{x\in\ell^2 : x_{2n+1}=0\;\forall n\in\mathbb N\}$.
Then it can be seen that both $A$ and $B$ are closed.

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projector on $A$, and $Q$ the orthogonal projector on $B$.
Clearly, $\operatorname{im} P \cap \operatorname{im} Q=\{0\}$.

Let $n\in \mathbb N$. We consider the vector $e_{2n}\in\ell^2$.
It can be shown that
$$
Qe_{2n} =e_{2n}
$$
and
$$
Pe_{2n} =(1+\frac1{n^2})^{-1}\left( e_{2n} + \frac1n e_{2n+1}\right).
$$
Calculating the norm of the latter yields
$$
\|PQe_{2n}\|=\|Pe_{2n}\|=(1+\frac1{n^2})^{-1/2}\to 1
\qquad (n\to\infty)
$$
Thus $\|PQ\|=1$.

Comment: Subspaces $A$ and $B$ are kissing at infinity! This is an instructive example (+1) thanks for the nice work. If I observe correctly, then a main feature making the example work, is that $A+B$ is dense, but *not closed* in $\ell^2$ (maybe modulo some index redefinition).
Or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: yes this is a standard example to show that the sum of two closed subspaces does not need to be closed.

Comment: But assuming that the sum of subspaces is closed then yields the strict "less than one" for the norm, cf [Norm estimate for a product of two orthogonal projectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3092323/316749) .